# Pinecone query not bringing up any matches?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, openai-api, pinecone

Here is what I have done - Converted a Snowflake schema into vectors and uploaded them to a Pinecone vector DB.

However when I try to run a query against the Pinecone DB, it does not bring up any results.

I have used this as reference: https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/openai
I know I am able to access the Pinecone db because when I try index.describe_index_stats(), it gives me the description of my vector db.

Here is what I have done:

```
from openai import OpenAI
import pinecone

client = OpenAI(api_key="my_API_key")
pinecone_client = pinecone.Pinecone(api_key='api_key', environment='my_env')
index = pinecone_client.Index('Index_name')

query = "give me the list of clients"

xq = client.embeddings.create(input=query, model=MODEL).data[0].embedding

if pinecone_client.describe_index(index_name).status['ready']:
    res = index.query(vector=xq, top_k=1, include_metadata=True)
    
else:
    print("server not ready")

for match in res['matches']:
    print(f"{match['score']:.2f}: {match['metadata']['text']}")
```

Ideally res should include a match that is similar to my query but all i am getting is an empty list.